# R: Add breaks in x-axis (date) in ggplot timeseries plot

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, axis-labels

For each day (Two weeks: `2015-01-01` - `2015-01-15`), I have 24 (hourly values) to plot using R ggplot2 package. The date column `dateChr` (`character format`) looks like follows:

```
> str(Data$dateChr)
chr [1:360] "1/1/2015 2:00" "1/1/2015 3:00" "1/1/2015 4:00" "1/1/2015 5:00" 
"1/1/2015 6:00" "1/1/2015 7:00" ...
```

Here is the code, I am using:

```
ggplot() + 
geom_line(data = Data, aes(x = dateChr, y = val1, group=1), color = "red") +
geom_line(data = Data, aes(x = dateChr, y = val2, group=1), color = "blue") +
theme_bw() +
xlab("Date") + 
ylab("Value")
```

The plot looks like this:

[image: plot]

The `x-axis` looks terrible. I would like to add breaks in the `x-axis` so that it only shows dates (no hours or timestamps) in 4 days break i.e., 2015-01-01, 2015-01-04, 2015-01-08 and so on. Can someone suggest me how do I add such breaks?

Comment: `?ggplot2::scale_x_date()`

Comment: make your dateChr column into dates. `lubridate` package will do this nicely

Comment: @RichardTelford: I have not used lubridate I think. Care to explain a bit?

Comment: there are functions such as `dmy_hm` which will convert text into dates

Answer (score 2):

By using the character type variable `dateChr`, the OP has choosen a *discrete* x-axis.

The `scale_x_discrete()` function can be used to customize the appearance of a discrete axis. According to `help("discrete_scale")`, it takes a `break` parameter which controls the breaks (and labels). One possible type of input to `break` is

> a function, that when called with a single argument, a character
>   vector giving the limits of the scale, returns a character vector
>   specifying which breaks to display.

So, with the additional call to `scale_x_discrete()`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = Data, aes(x = dateChr, y = val1, group=1), color = "red") +
  geom_line(data = Data, aes(x = dateChr, y = val2, group=1), color = "blue") +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Date") + 
  ylab("Value") + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = function(x) x[seq(1, length(x), by = 4*24)])
```

we get

[image]

which shows breaks and labels every 4 days.

---

Now, the OP has requested to *only show dates (no hours or timestamps)*. This requires to manipulate `dateChr` but only for plotting the labels:

```
# define named functions for breaks
my_breaks <- function(x) x[seq(1, length(x), by = 4*24)]
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = Data, aes(x = dateChr, y = val1, group=1), color = "red") +
  geom_line(data = Data, aes(x = dateChr, y = val2, group=1), color = "blue") +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Date") + 
  ylab("Value") + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = my_breaks,
                   labels = my_breaks(stringr::str_sub(Data$dateChr, 1, 10)))
```

[image]

#### Data

Unfortunately, the OP has not provided the data to reproduce the graph. So, I had to make up my own sample dataset which simulates OP's data.

```
df1 <- data.table::fread("https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/datagetter?product=wind&application=NOS.COOPS.TAC.MET&begin_date=20150101&end_date=20150114&station=8594900&time_zone=GMT&units=metric&interval=h&format=csv")
df2 <- data.table::fread("https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/datagetter?product=wind&application=NOS.COOPS.TAC.MET&begin_date=20150101&end_date=20150114&station=8638999&time_zone=GMT&units=metric&interval=h&format=csv")

Data <- data.frame(dateChr = format(as.POSIXct(df1$`Date Time`), "%d/%m%/%Y %H:%M"),
                   val1 = df1$Speed, val2 = df2$Speed, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(Data)
```

> ```
> 'data.frame': 336 obs. of  3 variables:
>  $ dateChr: chr  "01/01/2015 00:00" "01/01/2015 01:00" "01/01/2015 02:00" "01/01/2015 03:00" ...
>  $ val1   : num  1.42 0.51 0.91 2.08 1.3 1.27 2.08 2.33 1.7 1.95 ...
>  $ val2   : num  1.1 0.1 2.7 3.5 4 4.1 4.1 4 3.8 4.4 ...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but in case anyone else is looking. As mentioned in the comments, it would be best to convert the date variable to a true date field, then use `scale_x_date`.

```
library(ggplot2)
Data$dateDate <- lubridate::dmy_hm(Data$dateChr)

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = Data, aes(x = dateDate, y = val1, group=1), color = "red") +
  geom_line(data = Data, aes(x = dateDate, y = val2, group=1), color = "blue") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_date("Date", date_breaks = "4 days") + 
  ylab("Value")
```